# Quit Tkinter application by calling class method

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, python-class, tcltk

I am trying to build a splash screen that I will be able to call from an external application using Tkinter. I'd like to define my GUI in a class, like this:

```py
class Splash:  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.root = tk.Tk()  
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)  
        self.root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Initializing...")  
        self.label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)  
        self.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode='indeterminate')  
        self.progbar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10)  
        self.progbar.start(40)  
          
        self.root.update_idletasks()  
        self.root.geometry(  
            "+{}+{}".format(  
                int((self.root.winfo_screenwidth() - self.root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2),  
                int((self.root.winfo_screenheight() - self.root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2),  
            )
        )
        root.mainloop()
        
    def close(self):  
        self.root.destroy()
```

The goal is that in my external app, I can create a `Splash` object, run my initialization, and then call the `close` function on the `Splash` object to close the splash screen, like this:

```py
import time  
import Splash  

x = Splash.Splash()
time.sleep(5) # App initialization happens here.
x.close()
```

This isn't working, as `root.mainloop()` blocks, and the initialization functions are never actually reached. This variation also does not work:

```py
class Splash:  
    closeRequest = False

    def __init__(self):
        
        # Everything up until root.mainloop(), as shown above, goes here
        
        while not self.closeRequest:  
            self.root.update_idletasks()  
            self.root.update()
    
    def close(self):  
        self.closeRequest = True
```

**How can I accomplish my goal here?** I'd prefer not to use threads for this, but please feel free to share threads-based solutions as well.

Comment: Don't use mainloop within a component. Look into using `.after()`

Comment: I’m not looking to delay closing the window for a set number of seconds—I’m trying to write a function that an external program can call on a `Splash` object to cause the window to close.

Comment: What is the mechanism that allows an external program to call a function in your Splash app?

Comment: My external program is (basically) another Python script, so the mechanism is just `import`. I want to create a `Splash` object in the other script, run initialization steps, and then close the splash screen.

Comment: If you are importing this script from your program, then it is not an external  program.

Comment: You can consider the whole thing to be a single program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate `Splash.py` and `main.py` files you can do this:

Splash.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Splash:  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.root = tk.Tk()  
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)  
        self.root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Initializing...")  
        self.label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)  
        self.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode='indeterminate')  
        self.progbar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10)  
        self.progbar.start(40)  
          
        self.root.update_idletasks()  
        self.root.geometry(  
            "+{}+{}".format(  
                int((self.root.winfo_screenwidth() - self.root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2),  
                int((self.root.winfo_screenheight() - self.root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2),  
            )
        )
        #root.mainloop()
        
    def close(self):  
        self.root.withdraw()
```

main.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from Splash import Splash

def mainWindow(x):
    x.close()
    mainwindow=tk.Tk()
    mainwindow.title("Calculator")
    mainwindow.geometry('480x240')
    buttonOne = tk.Button(mainwindow,text='1')
    
x = Splash()
x.root.after(5000, lambda: mainWindow(x))
tk.mainloop()
```

Note that the class `Splash` doesn't execute `root.mainloop()` and I use `self.root.withdraw()` to close the splash screen.

You can have whatever tkinter code you like in the `def mainWindow()` function which closes the splash screen and starts another screen.